# Document map in vim

Tags: vim, navigation

Before I used Vim I used Notepad++.
What I miss in Vim is the Notepad++ document map.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y6hE0SdgsQ)
Sublime text editor has similar document map.
Yes I know you can navigate in Vim using commands as `gg`, `G` and many others but sometimes I like to have an overview of the entire document and click in it to go directly to that part of the file.

I tried to find out on the internet if there are Vim plugins to realize this but couldn't find anything about it. 
Is there a way in Vim to view a document map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature goes against Vim's philosophy ("Vim is not a fancy GUI editor"; cp. `:help design-not`), because such feature would be impossible in the terminal and therefore not cross-platform.

However, people have implemented this as a plugin (for GVIM and Windows, at least). Check out the [CodeOverview plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2888); it provides just that.

Comment: It is not a nice plugin but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [minimap-vim](https://github.com/koron/minimap-vim) but yeah, I second what Ingo said in his first sentence.